# Perform a grep in an if

Tags: shell

How could I perform a grep in an if statement? I'd like to check if a string contains a sub-string.

```
DSU_DIFF="$(sudo php app/console d:s:u --dump-sql)"
# I want to check if the $DSU_DIFF contains the sub-string "Nothing to update"
if [ "$DSU_DIFF" | grep "Nothing to update" ]
   then
       echo "Contains substring"
else
   echo "No substring contained"
fi
```

This is syntactically wrong, how should I try this?

Comment: `if sudo php app/console d:s:u --dump-sql | grep -qF "Nothing to update"; then echo "Contains substring"; else echo "No substring contained"; fi`

Comment: The syntax is valid, but the semantics are wrong.  Piping the empty string to grep, which ignores the input from the pipe but instead tries to read from a file named ]  is not what you want.  Remember, [ is not an operator, but a command.  (Caveat, the shell syntax is valid, but you are calling [ with an invalid argument list.  It's debatable whether that constitutes valid syntax)

Comment: It's invalid `[` syntax, since technically the argument list is treated as a list of tokens to parse. The syntax error is not providing the mandatory `]` token at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `grep` for that?

You can use `case`:

```
case "$DSU_DIFF" in
    *'Nothing to update'*)
        echo "Contains substring";;
    *)
        echo "No substring contained";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

@melpomene is right, but just in case:

```
if echo "$DSU_DIFF" | grep "Nothing to update"; then
    echo "Contains substring"
else
   echo "No substring contained"
fi
```

Comment: I suggest using the `-q` flag for grep to suppress output.